Odd cropping of Meta Icon on profile page
I went to a user's profile page that I saw had joined a chat room. On that user's profile page, I noticed the image for the Meta Stack Exchange was oddly positioned, offset too high, causing it to be cropped.

This bug is persistent across refreshing (using 100% zoom with Chrome myself), and was reproduced by another user using Chrome and Edge, though they mentioned it "only at 33% and 67% zoom. Any other zoom setting 25% (min) to 500% (max) it looks fine." And they couldn’t reproduce (at any zoom setting) when using Firefox, Safari, or Opera.
As mentioned in the comments, Peilonrayz can repro on Chromium at 110% viewport. Chromium reports the icon as having a height and width of 15.99px. But the CSS pretty clearly uses 16px (".favicon{width:16px;height:16px").

I can repro on Chromium at 110% viewport. Chromium reports the icon as having a height and width of 15.994px. But the CSS pretty clearly uses 16px (".favicon{width:16px;height:16px").

Related (if not a Duplicate): Site icons all cut off/incorrectly cropped in Hot Network Questions list
